# How to change a cells colour based on a cell on a seperate sheet being empty

Tags: syntax, google-sheets-formula, match, formula, conditional-formatting

I'm struggling to nail this. I'm trying to use conditional formatting on google sheets to change the colour of a group of cells based on a cell in a different sheet being empty.

So for example I have a sheet called "Controls" with an empty cell, M13, to write a persons name. Once that cell has had text inputted I would like a group of cells, BE2:BN25, to change colour to white so as effectively 'unlock' them for data entry.

I've tried =NOT(ISBLANK("Controls!M13")) but it's not changing colour once some text has been entered to that cell.

Is this possible on google sheets or am I just making a glaringly obvious error?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: What i would like is for all the tables to be be coloured dark blue so they aren't avaliable for use until you add a name to the controls sheet which would then change the table to white giving you access to input on that table. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OD96e96l7xko4LaCQ8TVbNYAPy-69ADfZOgLJej22kk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet is private

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("Controls!M13")))
```